# Data lost in Athena query results

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv

I am using AWS Athena to query from AWS Glue Crawler, but part of the data doesn't show up in the query result. What should I do?

Here is the sample of the original data:
[image]

Anh here is the data queried from AWS Athena:

[image]

Comment: I have no clue which application this is, but looks like the records where Message-ID is formatted like `xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx` do import the NumberOfMessages, but the records formatted like `xxxxxxxxxxx-YYYY.MM.DD` do not(?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how the original data is escaped and delimited. Look into the raw .csv file and see if all cases of *Message-Id* are concidered strings (i.e. that they are quoted) and if *NumberOfMessage* is concidered a number without quotes.

If fields are not correctly escaped and quoted, then the crawler has a hard time figuring out where one cell ends and the next one starts.

Comment: If this is the case, you can easily reformat the data using this plugin https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/

Comment: I did not know about that one, thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I have checked but there is no issue like that. All data in Message-Id are strings and all data in NumberOfMessage are int.

Comment: Do check the comment by @BdR. It seems suspicious that only the recoreds where date is not in the Id contain NumberOfMessages.